# Samsung XCover: can't turn SD external memory into internal memory, even with adb

Tags: internal-storage, internal-sd

I have a Samsung XCover 4s, android 11, and I can't find a way to turn a part (or even the entire card) of my sd card into internal memory. With ADB I tried to follow this tutorial:

```
$ sm list-disks adoptable                                                                                                                                                                          
disk:179,32
$ sm partition disk:179,32 mixed 75 # 75% as external
```

unfortunately when I restart my external storage is smaller… but my internal memory still has the same size. Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: there is second step 'migrate data' required (but is suppressed intentionally on oneui)

Comment: @alecxs Uhm interesting… so is there a workaround in oneui? Can I 'migrate data' from adb (I can't find how), or in a different manner?

Comment: no, but try "force allow apps on external" in developer options + *'adb shell pm set-install-location 2'* this might affect new apps installed in adoptable-storage by default. or try 3rd party app (like Link2SD) which also has option for native App2SD (no root/no 2nd partition required)